# How to resolve the MTouch Error in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My xamarin.forms version is 3.6.0.293080. When I set my Linker behavior to Link SDK's only/Don't link, I get to see this error.

Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "PanCardView.Factory.CardViewFactoryRule" reference from "PanCardView, Version=1.0.6607.25119, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" (MT2002) (Budocode.iOS)

Comment: Add more content to this with just the error no one would be able to tell you what the problem is, in any case look for `PanCardView.Factory.CardViewFactoryRule` and see if it is available

Comment: @G.hakim I do not see PanCardView.Factory.CardViewFactoryRule in my project.

Comment: Then add PanCardView to your iOS project and it should work